# pd.read_sql method to count number of rows in a large Access database

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to read the number of rows in a large access database and I am trying to find the most efficient method. Here is my code:

```
driver = 'access driver as string'
DatabaseLink = 'access database link as string'
Name = 'access table name as string'

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={' + driver + '};DBQ=' + DatabaseLink +';') 
cursor = conn.cursor()
AccessSize = cursor.execute('SELECT count(1) FROM '+ Name).fetchone()[0]
connection.close()
```

This works and `AccessSize` does give me an integer with the number of rows in the database, however it takes far too long to compute (my database has over 2 million rows and 15 columns).

I have attempted to read the data through `pd.read_sql` and used the `chunksize` functionality to loop through and keep counting the length of each chunk but this also takes long. I have also attempted `.fetchall` in the cursor execute section but the speed is similar to `.fetchone`

I would have thought there would be a faster method to quickly calculate the length of the table as I don't require the entire table to be read. My thought is to find the index value of the last row as this essentially is the number of rows but I am unsure how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: what is the DB engine?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by engine? The access database is a '.mdb' file.

Comment: Try a useless `WHERE` on key or index: `'SELECT count(1) FROM {} WHERE id > 0'.format(Name)`

Comment: @Parfait Unfortunately the database doesn't have a suitable keys or indexes in any of its columns.

Comment: That's very interesting. Consider setting that up on the queried table(s).

Comment: @Vik my bad, I didn't understand it was a _MS Access_ database. Resources online suggest select count(*) on access is slow. are records fixed length? perhaps you can get a good enough estimate by dividing file_size / record_length

Answer (score 1):

From comment to the question:

> Unfortunately the database doesn't have a suitable keys or indexes in any of its columns.

Then you can't expect good performance from the database because *every* SELECT will be a table scan.

I have an Access database on a network share. It contains a single table with 1 million rows and absolutely no indexes. The Access database file itself is 42 MiB. When I do

```python
t0 = time()
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM Table1", cnxn)
print(f'{time() - t0} seconds')
```

it takes 75 seconds and generates 45 MiB of network traffic. Simply adding a primary key to the table increases the file size to 48 MiB, but the same code takes 10 seconds and generates 7 MiB of network traffic.

TL;DR: Add a primary key to the table or continue to suffer from poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

2 million should not take that long. I have Use pd.read_sql(con, sql) like this:

```
con = connection
sql = """ my sql statement
here"""

table = pd.read_sql(sql=sql, con=con)
```

Are you doing something different?

In my case I am using a db2 database, maybe that is why is faster.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately this takes the same time as the method posted in the question.